# Commutative diagram for hidden subgroup representation of graph automorphism

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

The hidden subgroup representation of the graph automorphism problem is defined in the section 10.2 of [QUANTUM ALGORITHMS FOR PROBLEMS IN NUMBER
THEORY, ALGEBRAIC GEOMETRY, AND GROUP THEORY](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.6126v1.pdf). It is as follows.

> [image]

I would like to define the the problem as follows.

> For a graph $\Gamma$ with $n$ vertices, a map $\varphi : S_{n} \to
> > \text{Mat}\left(\mathbb{C}, N \right)$ ($\text{Mat}\left(\mathbb{C}, N
> > \right)$ is the algebra of all $N \times N$ matrices over the complex
>   numbers $\mathbb{C}$) from the group $S_{n}$ is said to have hidden
>   subgroup structure if there exists a subgroup
>   $\text{Aut}\left(\Gamma\right)$ of $S_{n}$, called a hidden subgroup,
>   an injection $\ell_\varphi : S_{n}/\text{Aut}\left(\Gamma\right) \to
> > \text{Mat}\left(\mathbb{C}, N \right)$, called a hidden injection,
>   such that the diagram
>
> [image]
>
> is commutative, where $S_{n}/\text{Aut}\left(\Gamma\right)$ denotes
>   the collection of right cosets of $\text{Aut}\left(\Gamma\right)$ in
>   $S_{n}$, and where $\nu : S_{n}/\text{Aut}\left(\Gamma\right)$ is the
>   natural map of $S_{n}$ onto $S_{n}/\text{Aut}\left(\Gamma\right)$. We
>   refer to the group $S_{n}$ as the ambient group and to the set
>   $\text{Mat}\left(\mathbb{C}, N \right)$ as the target set.
>
> The hidden subgroup version of the graph automorphism problem is to
>   determine a hidden subgroup $\text{Aut}\left(\Gamma\right)$ of $S_{n}$
>   with the promise that $\text{Aut}\left(\Gamma\right)$ is either
>   trivial or maintain a particular order depending on the type of
>   $\Gamma$.

Is my way of defining graph automorphism capturing the whole idea?